# 4 Triangle in a box with image inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, svg

> [image: Result Needed]

I am in need of assistance creating something like the image above either in CSS / jQuery / SVG / Canvas

Each triangle will contain an image that needs to be cropped to fit the triangle and everything needs to be responsive.

I managed in doing this via CSS border but for my surprise I couldn't add an image to it.

> [image: My result]

Any kind of tips or info is greatly appreciated.

Example resulted via CSS:

```
<div class="middle_section" style="height: 900px;">
    <div class="one_forth triangleMask for_1"></div>
    <div class="one_forth triangleMask for_2"></div>
    <div class="one_forth triangleMask for_3"></div>
    <div class="one_forth triangleMask for_4"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.middle_section .for_3,
    .middle_section .for_1{
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .middle_section .for_2,
    .middle_section .for_4{
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .middle_section .for_1:after {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 440px 808px 0px 808px;
        border-color: #ff0000 transparent transparent transparent;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:10px;
    }

    .middle_section .for_2:after {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 440px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 440px solid transparent;
        border-left: 808px solid lime;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top:10px;
    }

    .middle_section .for_3:after {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 808px solid transparent;
        border-right: 808px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 440px solid #4679BD;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:10px;
    }

    .middle_section .for_4:after {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 440px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 440px solid transparent;
        border-right: 808px solid pink;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top:10px;
        right:0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: can you provide your trying code

Comment: Code updated above

Comment: Thanks for the code, but what is your question? You say you want to do something, post code, but what does the code do? Why doesn't it work? Where's your problem with this code?

Comment: Hey Adrian and thanks for help, well the problem is that i cannot add images inside the triangles

Answer (score 0):

I made an example with CSS transform rotate:

```css
.wrapper {
  width:284px;
  height:281px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.top {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top:-100px;
  left: 40px;
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -105px;
  left: 40px;
}

.left {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: -102px;
  top: 41px;
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: -98px;
  top: 41px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="top">
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1"/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bottom">
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/2"/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="left">
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/3"/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/5"/>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, yeah but this is non responsive :( and the images are rotated